# Getting duplicate data of last index from database rather all data in Java

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, vector

```
java.util.Vector v = new Vector();
Model model = new Model();
v = model.getData();
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    model = (Model) v.elementAt(i);
    System.out.println(model.getName());
}
```

I am using this code to get data. First I've set data in vector object then trying to retrieved all data via for loop. However, my code doesn't work -- I'm getting the following error message:

[image: Getting output like this.]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get duplicates entries use [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). You have to remember to override `equals` and `hashcode` methods in the `Model` class.

```
import java.util.*;

Model model = new Model();
Set s = new HashSet(model.getData());

for (Object model : s) {
    if (model instanceOf Model) {
        System.out.println(((Model)model.getName()));
    }
}
```

For better performance you should use generic version of collections classes. So if we assume that your method `Model.getData()` has the following signature:

```
public Collection<Model> getData();
```

The above code could be written in this way:

```
import java.util.*;

Model model = new Model();
Set<Model> s = new HashSet<Model>(model.getData());

for (Model model : s) {
    System.out.println(model.getName());
}
```

Comment: @Bujutsu added example code. I saw that you retrieve data from database. In your database you have duplicates?

Comment: @lukaslew it does not work for me java.util.Set set=new HashSet(Model.getData());    
  
//  set=model.getData();
  for (Model model : set) {
      if (model instanceof Model) {
          System.out.println((model.getName()));
      }
  }

Comment: you used Set without generic type so you have set with objects. You cannot use for (Model model: set) because you will get compile error: `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Model`: http://ideone.com/UhlzLy